# How to properly assign a member value in a std::thread and read it from another?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an issue with multithreading where I probably lack understanding. I want to assign a member variable of an object inside a thread and then print the variable from another thread (or main in this case). It seems like I am doing something wrong, like there are two objects.

Here is a quick example:

thread_test.hpp

```
#pragma once                           
                                       
#include <iostream>                    
#include <chrono>                      
#include <thread>                      
                                       
class thread_test                      
{                                      
    public:                            
        thread_test ():                
            test_variable{}            
        {}                             
                                       
        int get_test_variable() const; 
        void updater_method();         
    private:                           
        /* private data */             
                                       
        int test_variable;             
};
```

thread_test.cpp

```
#include "thread_test.hpp"                                           
                                                                     
void thread_test::updater_method()                                   
{                                                                    
    int i{};                                                         
                                                                     
    while(true)                                                      
    {                                                                
        test_variable = ++i;                                         
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds{1800});
                                                                     
    }                                                                
}                                                                    
                                                                     
int thread_test::get_test_variable() const                           
{                                                                    
    return test_variable;                                            
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
                                                                    
#include "thread_test.hpp"
                                                                    
int main()
{
                                                                    
    thread_test obj{};
                                                                    
    std::thread updater_thread(&thread_test::updater_method, obj);
                                                                    
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << obj.get_test_variable() << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
                                                                    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./main
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I don't understand why the variable stays at the initialized value, because I am assigning it in the thread for the test object. Is there a better way to start the thread or should I start the thread from the class itself? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Assignments to variables aren't usually atomic, meaning you have a data-race.

Comment: `updater_thread(&thread_test::updater_method, std::ref(test));` in your case thread ctor takes `test` by value.

Comment: I renamed "test" to "obj" for readability

Comment: @rafix Yes, that works. Thank you. Do you want to post an official solution, so I can mark it as such?

Comment: Also, concurrent R/W to non-atomic variable is undefined behaviour. use `std::atomic_int`.

Comment: @Quimby Ah I thought it would only be important if you have to read accesses. Thank you

Comment: @neolith Well, you have a read access by printing the value :) It is undefined because the read could in theory see bitwise-partially written value which for integer is just another integer but for more complex types it really would be undefined.

Comment: @neolith - If there are *only* read access (i.e. no writing) there is no a problem.   It is having any concurrent writes of a non-atomic variable that cause undefined behaviour.    Consider what happens if one thread is part-way through a non-atomic write, and gets interrupted/preempted by another thread that does a read or a write.

Answer (score 3):

`std::thread` stores the arguments to be passed to the thread execution function *by value* (actually the function as well, relevant, if it's actually a functor, which is supported as well) – i.e. it creates copies of, which applies, too, to your test object `obj`. So the result is that the main thread and the worker thread operate each on their own, distinct instance of your `thread_test` class and thus the main thread never receives updates.

To avoid, you can either use a `std::reference_wrapper` or a pointer:

```
std::thread updater_thread(&thread_test::updater_method, std::ref(obj));
// or alternatively:
std::thread updater_thread(&thread_test::updater_method, &obj);
```

This way you only operate on one single instance. Yet another alternative (thanks, @[chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi), for the hint) is using a lambda:

```
std::thread updater_thread([&obj]() { obj.updater_method() });
//                           ^^^ optional, alternatively just a default &
```

Note, too, that updating and reading variables in general is not atomic and you might get confronted with race conditions. You can solve the issue by either using `std::atomic`, wrapping entire objects into or single members thereof, whichever suits better for you, or you protect access to the variables via a `std::mutex` or possibly a `std::shared_mutex`, if you want to allow simultaneous reads and only have the writes with exclusive access.

Comment: Another alternative: `std::thread updater_thread([&]{ obj.updater_method(); });`